# exception is not forwarded to parent methods

Tags: c#, exception

If an exception is happened in a Subfunction, I would like to have this exception also in the parent method. For example:

In my main Class I have such functions:

```
public static void ParentFunction(TraceWriter log)
{
   logger = log;               
   subFunction1(logger);     
}


static int subFunction1(TraceWriter log)
{
   try
   {
     SubFunction2(int param1,int param2)
     //Some Code here
   }
   catch( exception e)
   {
    //Some Code here
   }
}
```

In another c# class I have the definition for `SubFunction2`:

```
 public static void SubFunction2(int param1, int param2)
 {
   //Constructor
    SubFunction2();
 }
//if some exception in this function is happened, I would like to have also an exception in ParentFunction
private static void subFunction2()
{
   try
   {
     //Some Code here
   }
   catch( exception e)
   {
    //some code
   }
}
```

if some exception in `subFunction2()` is happened, I would like to have also an exception in ParentFunction. Ho should I change my code to achieve this aim?

Comment: then either omit the `catch` in `subfunction2` or re-throw it. Currently you handle it, and thus calling code has no clue that an exception was thrown in some inner call.

Comment: How can I re throw it? I dont want to omit catch in `subfunction2`

Comment: `catch(Exception e) { /* do some handling*/; throw; }`.